# How do I parse the output of `date -u` (unix date command, UTC) using moment.js?

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

I literally just noticed that the unix date command does not output iso8601 or RFC2822 format dates.

I've got some input json documents with the date specified as the output of unix `date -u`, e.g.: `Mon Oct 22 04:08:48 UTC 2018`.  My dates are always in `UTC` because they were generated with `date -u`.  (Next time I'll be smart and just use `date -u +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"` to get an iso8601 date.)

I've scoured the documentation for parsing and searched the web thoroughly, but can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I am trying to parse these using moment.js:

```
const instr = 'Mon Oct 22 03:53:08 UTC 2018';
const dateFormatString = "ddd MMM DD HH:mm:ss [UTC] GGGG";
const parsedDate = moment.utc(instr, dateFormatString, true);
```

It's still just giving me:

```
moment.invalid(/* Mon Oct 22 03:53:08 UTC 2018 */)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Example:

https://jsfiddle.net/1c3g0r4j/

```
var parseString  = 'Mon Oct 22 03:53:08 UTC 2018'; 
var formatString = 'ddd MMM DD HH:mm:ss [UTC] gggg';
var locale = 'en';
var strictParse = true;
var parsed = moment.utc(parseString, formatString, locale, strictParse);

alert(parsed.isValid())  //false
```

Comment: This looks like a bug. Changing the string to `Tue Oct 22...` works.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce your report of it working if the dayname is Tue

Comment: Interesting, @sneak. I wonder if it has something to do with my timezone.

Comment: interesting, even though the result isnt valid, if i take that parsed date and run it through toISOString() and parse it again, it works, except gives the day as tuesday and the year as 2019 instead of 2018 like it's supposed to:  https://jsfiddle.net/c1pbdtqs/1/

Comment: check the jsfiddle, i am explicitly specifying the locale there

Comment: I updated the Moment version on the fiddle — for me `Tue` now works: https://jsfiddle.net/b5qdxwec/

Comment: October 22 2018 was a Monday, though - and that's what's in my data.

looking at your working fiddle for Tue, it parses the year as 2019 (oct 22 2019 was a tuesday, yes, but the input string is 2018 and was a monday.)

Comment: Right, that's why I think it's a bug.

Comment: Ahhh, got it.  Thanks for your help!  It's always a relief when it's not something I'm doing wrong. :)

Comment: I tried using the locale year parse string `YYYY` — that works for Monday: https://jsfiddle.net/tpzv0hye/

Answer (score 0):

Mark Meyer above provides us with the solution, which appears to be using the locale-specific year token `YYYY`.

```
var parseString  = 'Mon Oct 22 03:53:08 UTC 2018'; 
var formatString = 'ddd MMM DD HH:mm:ss [UTC] YYYY';
var locale = 'en';
var strictParse = true;
var parsed = moment.utc(parseString, formatString, locale, strictParse);

alert(parsed.isValid())
alert(parsed.toISOString())
```